# Struts2 action setter method not thread safe?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am having a really weird issue.
I have a web app built with Struts2, two action file and one jsp file.
The function is to submit a form and get the csId from UI.
However, i found that if I open two windows to click on the form to submit different csId, i can see the csId get changed in the loop in the action.

I think action is thread safe but how can the other user's action change the csId in my action?
Please help.

There are two Action file:

```
public abstract class CustomerSegmentCrudBaseAction extends BaseAction {
    protected String csId;
    public String execute() throws PromotionException{
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getCsId() {
        return csId;
    }

    public void setCsId(String csId) {
        this.csId = csId;
    }
}

public class CustomerSegmentAddCustomerIdAction extends CustomerSegmentCrudBaseAction {

    public String execute(){ 
       for(int i = 0;i<10000;i++){
          log.info(java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getId() + " csId: " + csId);
       }
    }
}
```

jsp file:

```
<s:form action="add-ids-customer-segment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="var customerCount = getCustomerIdCount(); return confirm('Are you sure to upload ' + customerCount +' customers?');">
       <table><tbody><tr>
       <td class="cell">
           <s:textarea label="Customer ID" labelposition="false" id="csCustomerIds" name="csCustomerIds" value="" rows="2" cssClass="wide" theme="css_xhtml"/>
       </td>
       <td class="cell">
           <s:submit value="Add" theme="css_xhtml"/>
       </td>
       </tbody></table>
       <s:hidden name="csId" value="%{getCsId()}" />
   </s:form>
```

I also printed the thread id and i can see there are two different threads. The csId in one thread got changed to another csId in the other thread.

Wed Aug 29 10:55:40 2018 GMT  (http-bio-8663-exec-8) customersegment.ui.html.actions.edit.CustomerSegmentAddCustomerIdAction: thread id is: 44 csId: 8787

Wed Aug 29 10:55:40 2018 GMT  (http-bio-8663-exec-8) customersegment.ui.html.actions.edit.CustomerSegmentAddCustomerIdAction: thread id is: 44 csId: 8787

Wed Aug 29 10:55:40 2018 GMT (http-bio-8663-exec-8) customersegment.ui.html.actions.edit.CustomerSegmentAddCustomerIdAction: thread id is: 44 csId: 28475

Comment: Actions are created per-request, period, unless you've mistakingly used Spring and created a non-prototype action bean. If you have not done that, you'll need to provide a lot more info, because there's no normal circumstances under which this could happen.

Comment: i wish i see your answer earlier! Thanks Dave!

Comment: You should leave your answer, though (un-delete it). Self-answering questions is fine (there may be a dupe for this but it might be hard to search for). Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do confuse yourself with this logging command.

Struts 2 is executing every request in a single thread.
Does your Logger print the current thread id to see the difference?

Try to log also the current thread id with `log.info(java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getId() + " csId: " + csId)`.

Comment: yes, i printed the thread id and i can see there are two different threads. The csId in one thread got changed to another csId in the other thread.

Comment: this is not ok when I have two users change the csid in differernt threads, the value got messed up, I got this issue in real life system.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause that i use Spring to create action bean which by default the scope is singleton.
Change the scope to prototype.